# Forecasting the DB size in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Today, I got the New requirement from business to forecast the DB size in advance for new project.

Can any one know how can I forecast the DB Size in advance?

we have product which import the DATA from excel to DB the maximum size is any thing like 500 column and 15000 rows.

So, I want create the forecasting formula to find the excepted DB Size. for example if client upload the DATA 500 columns and 15000 Rows the excepted size would be =500*1500 but it's not give exact size.

Comment: We are using the SQL Express editions so we have to forecast the DB Size before install the software to client

Comment: Are you really planning on having 500 columns in a single table? Plan your schema properly first (normalization) and you'll be able to save some space.

Comment: While uploading the Excel file there is no column limit. because after uploading the data we convert data from column to rows.

Comment: Make that conversion process part of the data import then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column count is not enough, you have to know the data types and the length of the data.

Using this information, you can calculate the worst case scenario by adding up the maximum storage space required for the columns. For example an `NVARCHAR(20)` will require `40 bytes` when it stores a 20 characters long string.

Multiply this by the number of rows (this is an educated guess based on previous info).

This is your approximate growth.

Here is an example:

You have these columns:

- ID `INT`
- Name `NVARCHAR(64)`
- Description `NVARCHAR(256)`

Your row size is **4 bytes + 128 bytes + 512 bytes = 644 bytes** per row.

This is the worst case scenario, in reality the average will be less.

There is some overhead and you have to consider indexes, log files, backup space, and so on, they do take storage space.

Since you've mentioned, that this will be a SQL Server Express instance, you have a hard limit for DB size (more or less data and index size combined):

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express: **4GB**
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express: **10GB**
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012: **10GB**
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express: **10GB**

**Resources:**

- [Data Types (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)
- [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: ...and make sure you've taken into account backup space, how much archive space you need, reindexing, how much can your tempdb grow (based on your traffic and the amount of queries).

Comment: yeah, @MK_ is right, the calculation above is just the raw storage space, log files, backups, indexes, whatever will need more space.

Comment: @MK_ those are definitely  factors which need to be considered in capacity planning for the *server*, but aside from index space they do not count against the 10GB size limit on SQL Server Express Edition.

Comment: @alroc - when I initially wrote the comment, the author hasn't even mentioned SQL Express so I thought he was talking about space in general (trying to calculate it in order to see what kind of disk he needs). Still, as you've pointed out, indexes still do go towards the 10GB limit.

Comment: how can we consider the long file and index sizing? because I have checked the DB size after upload the excel data in log file it shows different 578 MB allocation size and 520 MB available size.

Comment: SQL Server stores data on so called pages (8KB fragments). These pages are not always 100% filled, so the space used on the disk and the size required to store the raw data can be different. Same for logs, but those are 4KB pages. Please read about transactions logs and page files in BOL for more info.

Comment: @nirav and almost forgot to mention that SQL Server does not allocate space page per page, but in bulk (configured by files), the default size and the growth rate can be configured in the database creation/file creation script. This means, SQL Server always allocates more space than it is actually using to store data.

Comment: It's means you never predicts the log file size for bulk upload.

Comment: The log file? Yes and no :) You can not say an exact size, but for inserts only, without indexes, whatever you can say, that it won't exceed the size of the data rounded up to the next step in growth size. This is only for the insert transaction, but don't forget, that you may have other transactions running at the same time. Other factors can also affect the required log file size. You can say, that it won't exceed the available space on the disk ;)

Comment: So I am assuming that we can not predict/guess the Log file and index size. Right?

Comment: Also We are using NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: Index size is approx the size of key columns + included columns + row id (primary key or rowid) + tree size + some overhead. the tree size is hard to predict. Log size is different, since all transactions are using - more or less - the same log file.

Comment: so if there is not transaction after uploading the file. means log file is zero.

Comment: nope :) it depends on the backup strategy set and other factors, but this conversation is way out of scope and will lead to a long comment list. I would suggest you to go to the documentation first, or we can go to the chat on SO. (I need about 1 hour from now to be available there)